# How to make macdeployqt use another qt-installaton?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, macdeployqt

The macdeployqt which comes with Qt SDK 1.1 is broken (it's already files on the Qt bugtracker).

How do I make macdeployqt use the libraries of another Qt-version I installed instead of Qt SDK 1.1?

I couldn't find a bash-environment variable for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macdeployqt should deploy Qt libraries which are linked to your binary. Use otool to check what libraries are linked.

To get more control over the deployment of libraries, I ended up rewriting macddeployqt to always deploy/link to my preferred library location.

Comment: Thank you. I'm interested in your version of macdeployqt. How about uploading it somewhere?